# Why wp_enqueue_style() is adding CSS class?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Why my stylesheet links are getting `-css` at the end?  How can I remove that ?

I have this in my custom function file:

```
function enqueue_styles_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');
```

When I check the source this is the output:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='//localhost:3000/wordpress/wp-content/themes/underscore/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Can you please explain why `-css` is getting added to the given id `bootstrap` ?

Comment: What's the problem with that!!! :o

Comment: There is no problem just wanted to know why its getting added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix `-css` exists to prevent collisions with other elements on the site.

The elements needs *some* `id` so you can manipulate it later per JavaScript, so there has to be a predictable naming scheme.